# Revapi continually fails upon configuration phase

Tags: java, api, revapi

I've been experimenting with revapi to detect when public interface updates occur. However, I'm unable to get the command-line script to run as it continually fails upon setup:

> 13:26:36.956 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultDependencyCollector - Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=10, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=0}
>   org.revapi.configuration.ConfigurationException: ValidationResult[errors=[Error[code=0, dataPath='/revapi/reporter/text/output', message='invalid type: null (expected string)']], missingSchemas=null]
>           at org.revapi.Revapi.analyze(Revapi.java:345)
>           at org.revapi.standalone.Main.run(Main.java:336)
>           at org.revapi.standalone.Main.main(Main.java:259)

Command line arguments:

```
revapi.sh -e org.revapi:revapi-java:0.5.2,org.revapi:revapi-reporting-text:0.3.4 --old=my-api.-1.0.0.jar --new=my-api.-1.0.1.jar -D revapi.reporter.text.minSeverity=BREAKING
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try [japicmp](http://siom79.github.io/japicmp/). It is easy to use and does not fail:

```
java -jar japicmp-0.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar -n new-version.jar -o old-version.jar
```